# Set payment receiver in Braintree

Tags: paypal, braintree

I need to set up a mobile payment facility where people can purchase goods directly from other users of my app service. I don't receive any of the payments, they go directly to the seller. Using the PayPal REST API, you can set the payment receiver to be someone other than yourself, but the docs say that the API is deprecated and you should use Braintree instead. Since I am domiciled in UK, I can't use Braintree Marketplace which does allow for multiple providers to be paid individually. So is it possible to just set the PayPal receiver in Braintree?

Comment: I recommend you look into [PayPal for Marketplaces](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/marketplaces/pp4mp/ "Link to PayPal for Marketplaces docs"). Keep in mind: "PayPal for Marketplaces is available to select partners for approved use cases. For more information, reach out to your PayPal account manager or [contact us](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/partner-program/contact-us?ref=marketplace "Contact PayPal about Marketplace")."

Comment: Thank you, I think that is exactly what I am looking for. Wish I'd found out about this sooner.